# Printing matlab figures in color

Tags: linux, matlab, printing, redhat

When I try to print a matlab figure from red hat 5, it always comes out greyscale, even when I print to file. I can get around this by saving the plot as a PNG and then printing that, but I'd like to be able to print matlab plots directly.

I've tried selecting "color" in the print dialog box and in print preview, but the images still come out greyscale.

How can I get matlab to print in color?

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f3-84718.html#f3-138419

Comment: Would also help to provide the code you're using to plot with.  It could be as simple as adding or tweaking an argument when generating the figure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the `printopt.m` file on your system. Specifically, you need to add the line

```
dev = '-dpsc2';
```

This sets the printer driver to "color postscript", as opposed to the default printer driver for RHEL which is greyscale postscript.

See [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/choosing-a-printer-driver.html) from the matlab documentation.